# Workflow Task Completion Conditions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I would like to prevent a task from being able to check as finished by a user until a specific field on an item in another list is filled .

So I add an if statement in the completion conditions of my task process -> if the field is empty -> send email to user -> wait for the field change

But the task is always getting marked as finished. How can I prevent it from being completed 100%?

Or can I disable the finish button on my task form until the completion conditions are fulfilled? Or is there another way to achieve my desired behaviour?

FYI: 2010 workflow engine without infopath on SP 2013 environment

Comment: Is it possible to change the task status?

Comment: Or is it possible only to change the outcome when I press one of the buttons without ending the task process?